# Using zsh extensions - why do I have to manually type "zsh" to get it to appear?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I am using Robby Russell's "oh-my-zsh" extension on OSX 10.5 Leopard.  However I find that it's not loaded by default.. when I start a new Terminal it uses the "default" ZSH prompt, and I must manually type "zsh" and press Return to get the "enhanced" prompt.  My `.zshrc` file lists the ZSH path as pointing to the oh-my-zsh directory:

This gets very annoying because every time I open a new tab I've got to type zsh again (as an aside is it possible to get a new tab to remember my current working directory?  I mainly write Rails apps so I'll have 2-3 windows open inside the same directory and it's frustrating to have to cd back into it every time).  Is there an easy way to get it automatically start oh-my-zsh when I open a terminal so I don't have to type zsh every time?

**EDIT**

I automatically installed oh-my-zsh following Robby's instructions on Github, so here's the .zshrc it created for me:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set to the name theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
export ZSH_THEME="maran"

# Comment this out to disable weekly auto-update checks
# export DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="false"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...
export     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr  /local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
export GIT_EDITOR="mate -w"
```

I tried changing the default shell to point to that but then I get an error saying it's been set to an illegal variable.  The $HOME variable points correctly to my home directory, but it doesn't seem to be loading until I type zsh in the terminal when I have the regular zsh prompt.

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `pstree -wp $$`

```
-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 00066 waynemolina /sbin/launchd
   \-+= 68844 waynemolina /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal -psn_0_704684
     \-+= 68845 root login -pfq waynemolina /bin/zsh
       \-+= 68846 waynemolina -zsh
         \-+= 68939 waynemolina pstree -wp 68846
           \--- 68940 root ps -axwwo user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in 10.4, *Terminal* has a preference for “When creating a new Terminal window” to either use `/usr/bin/login` or to let the user specify a command. I expect that *Terminal* in 10.5 has something similar.

Do you happen to have something like `zsh -f` as the specified command instead of using `/usr/bin/login` or a *zsh* invocation without `-f`? The `-f` option will cause *zsh* to ignore all the startup files except `/etc/zshenv` (i.e. it will ignore your `~/.zshrc`).

Another way to check this setting might be with `defaults read com.apple.Terminal Shell`. If it shows some output you have a custom setting. If it is blank or does not exist then you are probably still using the default of `/usr/bin/login`.

**Edited to add:**
In one of your shells with the default prompt (a new *Terminal* window or tab), check for the following:

- Does `set -o | fgrep rcs` show “on” for `norcs`?
- Does `[[ "$ZDOTDIR" -ef "$HOME" ]] || echo "ZDOTDIR=$ZDOTDIR"` show anything?

If one or both of these conditions are true, you'll need to track down where they are being set. Note that `norcs` might be set with any of `set +o rcs`, `set -o norcs`, `setopt norcs`, `unsetopt rcs`, or `set -f`. Also the option names are not case sensitive and may have underscores inserted anythere (`NO_rC___s` is the same as `norcs`). Look in `/etc/zshenv`, `/etc/zprofile`, `/etc/zshrc`, `/etc/zlogin`; and `.zshenv`, `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, and `.zlogin` from your ZDOTDIR directory.

It might also be useful to know the full parentage of your “default prompt” shells (`pstree -wp $$` if you have [`pstree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pstree) from (e.g.) [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)). Maybe the normal ‘rc’ process is being interrupted by something like `zsh -f` in an ‘rc’ file.

Comment: It was using /usr/bin/login according to the settings, but I changed it to /bin/zsh and it's still running the "default" zsh prompt and not my enhanced one.

Comment: I tried both commands you posted, rcs is "off" and ZDOTDIR is empty.

Comment: Do you mean that you see `norcs                 off` (which is the default and means that your ‘rc’ files should be used)? The debug echos you put in based on Ryan's answer also seem to indicate that `norcs` is off for your “New Tab”/“New Window” case. I just wanted to clarify since 'rcs is "off"' is actually the opposite of 'norcs is "off"'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know too much about how Mac OS X works with shells, but in general I find it useful to sprinkle some echo statements around my initialization files, to make sure that they are being sourced. So, in your .zshrc file, you could put a line that says `echo "Loading .zshrc"`. And so on. The presence or absence of these echo statements when you start a new shell (or open a new tab) should help you diagnose the problem.

As for the directory changing problem, there are two potential solutions:
1. Use screen, and forget about tabs.
2. Write a function to echo the current directory to a file somewhere, then put that function in your precmd, and then add a line in .zshrc to read that file and cd to it. To be more specific (but untested!):

```
PWD_SAVE_FILE="$HOME/.pwd_save"
function savepwd {
  pwd > "$PWD_SAVE_FILE"
}

function precmd {
  savepwd
}

cd "`cat "$PWD_SAVE_FILE"`"
```

Comment: +1 for ‘echo debug’ technique; just be sure to remove them (or comment them out) when done, otherwise the echo output from non-login ‘rc’ files (.zshenv, .zshrc, and the global equivalents) can confuse tools that ssh-in and directly run commands (e.g. rsync, git)

Comment: I did an echo and it was outputted properly when I loaded a new command prompt.  It's also run when I type the "zsh" command, so it's getting loaded but for some reason the enhanced prompt isn't appearing until I type zsh manually

Comment: Well, I don't actually have a Mac, so I can't help you with Mac-specific weirdness. Only general weirdness, and possibly zsh-specific weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.  It was due to having a .zlogin in my home directory.  Once I removed .zlogin oh my zsh worked

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your `~/.zshrc` file for debugging purposes:

Right after this line:

```
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
```

Put:

```
echo $HOME
echo $ZSH
```